# ADFS login authentication sample on android using auth0

Tags: android, authentication, adfs, auth0

I am trying to develop ADFS login authentication using `Auth0` in `Android` app.

Am unable to find proper document on ADFS login.Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Auth0 against ADFS, but you can use ADA SDK for Android to work with ADFS 2012R2. 2012R2 only supports auth code grant flow without id_token. A .NET client is available with a pointer to the ADAL SDK for Android at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx

On 2016, the OAuth support is much richer. Some examples (but with .NET client) is available at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development. You can then augment with ADAL SDK for Android.

Thanks //Sam (@MrADFS)